# Swagger: type vs format

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm new to the OpenAPI specification. When looking through the documentation and guides I understand the major parts of it. However, I can seem to grasp the difference between type and format.

An example from the swagger tutorial pet store is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1u4V.png). In the example the parameter is both a **type:integer** and **format:int64**. What is the difference between them and why do both exits? Doesn't they tell the same info?

Answer (score 1):

type is a numeric data type in open-API specification where the format is how you define it with **specific precision**.

As for an integer type, there can be these formats:

**int32:** defines the **type** is **integer**, and the precision as **32 bits**. So, it will take a memory of 4 bytes and the range will be `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

**int64:** defines the **type** is **integer**, and the precision as **64 bits**. So, it will take a memory of 8 bytes and the range will be `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://graphql-faas.github.io/OpenAPI-Specification/versions/2.0.html#data-types). Basically, format is optional and is only there for defining the data type more detailed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).